# How do I programmatically check or uncheck my checkbox with Angular 8?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

This is my checkbox. How do I programmatically uncheck or check the checkbox via a function?

`<input name="Purchased" [(ngModel)]="Purchased" type="checkbox" id="test1" />`

`<label for="test1">Purchased Item</label>`

Answer (score 1):

input type checkbox has checked property, checked  receive true or false, is not necessary to change value of variable Purchase since is already bind, so yo only need to input if is check or not, you can use

```
<input name="Purchased" [(ngModel)]="Purchased" type="checkbox" id="test1" 
 [checked]="functionToDetermineIfCheckOrNot()"/>
```

Or you can have a isChecked var use

```
 <input name="Purchased" [(ngModel)]="Purchased" type="checkbox" id="test1" 
 (click)="isChecked = !isChecked"
 [checked]="isChecked"/>
```

Hope this help you, regards

Comment: **Nop**  (sorry the downvote). Not use [(ngModel)] and [checked] in the same tag. If you use [(ngModel)] simply change the value of the variable  in .ts, [(ngModel)] is two binding, that's, if you check in .html, the variable change its value.

Answer (score 0):

First of all variable name must be in lowerCamelCase or UPPER_CASE,

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-w8tdxd?file=src/app/app.component.ts example